# Power BI -- why are we using sum?

Tags: powerbi

I have data like
|Sales amount|Full name|
|------------|---------|
|320         |James fu |
|430         |Alice k. |
|620         |James fu |

In this case, I am going to make a graph which x-axis is sales amount and y-axis is full name.
Why should I make a new value named 'Sales = SUM([Sales amount])' using DAX?
I am following youtube, but I cannot understand why he is making a new value instead of using sales amount. I tried using sales amount, and the graph appeared the same as when I used new value.

Answer (score 1):

When you use your data just to show it in a simple graph you do not need to create a measure - your Power BI will do it for you. "He" creates the measure for different reasons like naming or using the measure in other calculations like this:

```
Sales = SUM([Sales amount])
...

Alice Sales = 
         CALCULATE(
               [Sales]
               ,tableName[Full name]="Alice k."
         )

Alice k. rate =
        DIVIDE(
           [Alice Sales]
           ,CALCULATE([Sales],ALL(tableName))
        )
```

As you see I used the measure twice and didn't wrote its code, just name. Note that, with different filters and environment this measures can returns different results. Naming is also an important part it helps to know what exactly measure returns.

Answer (score 0):

The actual answer is that using the column directly (called an implicit measure) is not best practice, since this will not work when using e.g. Excel to analyze the data model.

Having an explicit measure solves this issue, and is considered to be the best practice when developing your data model.

Answer (score 0):

If your summary data is in one column (just like [Sales Amount] Column), then It doesn't matter if you create a measure or not.
Now let's change the scenario a little. If You were needed 2 columns to calculate Sales Amount ([Unit Price] and [Quantity]), then what would you do ? Probably you would create a new column and multiply [unit Price] * [Quantity] columns and then put the resulting column into your chart or whatever.

```
Sales_Amount(Calculated_Column) = [Unit Price] * [Quantity])
```

That's correct; but performance-wise you would use your system resources carelessly in that case. Each new column means taking up more space, and slower performance. With creating a simple measure in this case makes a lot of difference while saving space. For Example

```
Sales_Amount(Measure) = SUMX(Sales_Table, [Unit Price] * [Quantity]).
```

Now pick the one who suits you the best.